# Topological cone using cosets

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

The topological cone is defined as $(S^1 \times [0,1]) / (S^1 \times \{1\})$. This is a quotient group that which elements are the cosets of $S^1 \times \{1\}$. Now I'm trying to understand how do these form the cone. The cosets are of the form $(1,0) + S^1 \times \{1\} , (0,1) + S^1 \times \{1\}$ e.g $(x,y) + S^1 \times \{1\}$, where $(x,y) \in S^1$ right?

So if $S^1 \times \{1\} = \{(x,y) \mid \|(x,y)\| = 1 \} \times \{1\} = \{(x,y,1) \mid \|(x,y,1)\| = 1 \}$, then is for example $(1,0) + S^1 \times \{1\} = \{(x,y,1) \mid \|(1+x,y,1) = 1\} \in (S^1 \times [0,1]) / (S^1 \times \{1\})$?

The other way to think about the set $(S^1 \times [0,1]) / (S^1 \times \{1\})$ seems to be that all elements of $ (S^1 \times \{1\})$ are being "collapsed" to zero? which would make sense since $ (S^1 \times \{1\})$ defines just the tip of the cone at $z=1$.

I have hard time with the second interpreation since I cannot formalize it in any way. It seems to be just one of those things that you just have to accept... How is this formalized?

Comment: Your question makes little sense. $S^1 \times [0,1]$ is not a group, so the concept of a "coset" is not applicable to its subsets, "addition" expressions such as $(1,0) + S^1 \times \{1\}$ are not defined, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE. Because there is no (natural) group structure on the cylinder $S^1 \times [0, 1]$, there is no real way of getting your proposed group-theoretic definition off the ground.

On the other hand, here is how we formalize the second notion  of “collapsing”. The idea is to impose a certain equivalence relation on $S^1 \times [0, 1]$. The denominator of the expression $S^1 \times [0, 1] / S^1 \times \{1\}$ specifies the equivalence classes of the relation: $(x, 1) \sim (y, 1)$ for all $x, y \in S^1$, and all other points $(x, t)$ for $x \in S^1$ and $t \in [0, 1)$ are inequivalent to each other (i.e. their equivalence classes are singletons). This set of equivalences is then topologized with the [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) to give the set of equivalence classes the shape of a cone.

Finally, let me mention that when you are working with an object that is both a group and a space (see under “quotients and normal subgroups” [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group#Properties)) the group-theoretic/“cosets” and topological/ “equivalence classes” notions of quotient object do coincide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How did you come up with the relation $(x, 1) \sim (y, 1)$ from $ S^1 \times \{0\}$? Specifically where did the $1$ come from for $(x, 1) \sim (y, 1)$?

Comment: @MatthewConagh it was a typo, see my edit. It should have been $S^1 \times \{1\}$ as in your original problem statement.